# useState async problem it does not update my list

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set DataList before executing an API call.

but the dataList contains nothing while executing API call.

my codes run with following steps.

1. when button is clicked --> execute onSubmit().
2. getSortedId function runs before executing an API call to get sorted data.
3. executes API call.

but my API call fails because of missing dataList.

I know hooks run with async way.

but how should I submit API call with proper dataList.

```
 const [ dataList, setDataList ] = useState<any>([]); //set Hooks
//a filtering function
  async function getSortedId() {

       await selected.map(data => {
        console.log("transaction_id", data.transaction_id);

         //set sorted Data to datalist
        setDataList((dataList : any) => [...dataList, data.transaction_id]);
      })
  }

 const onSubmit = (data : any) => {
    let refundMsg = "";
    getSortedId();
  
    axios.put("/api/v1/updates", {
      params: {
        "refundIdList" : dataList, //dataList should have some value but it contains nothing.
        "refundReason" : refundMsg,
        "reasonEtcReason" : data.reasonEtcReason,
        "feeUserPay" : data.feeUserPay ? 1 : 0,
        "penaltyFeeUserPay" : data.penaltyFeePartnerPay ? 1 : 0,
        "penaltyFeeUtPay:" : data.penaltyFeeUtPay ? 1 : 0,
        "penaltyFeePartnerPay" : data.penaltyFeePartnerPay ? 1 : 0,       
      }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("response", res);
    }).catch(err => { 
      console.log("Error : ", err);
    })
    }
  };
 return (
    <Button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit()} > Save </Button>
  )
```

Comment: Don't call `getSortedId` inside `onSubmit` - rather, have a `useEffect` hook with dependecy on `selected` (from `getSortedId` function) which updates the `dataList`.

Comment: `getSortedId` doesn't need to be `async` since there is nothing asynchronous happening in your function and you are ignoring the returned promise anyway inside `onSubmit`.
Also you are overwriting the value of `dataList` with each `selected` entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `useEffect` hook to call the api when `dataList` changes

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState<any>([]); //set Hooks
//a filtering function
  function getSortedId() {

  selected.map(data => {
    console.log("transaction_id", data.transaction_id);

    //set sorted Data to datalist
    setDataList((dataList: any) => [...dataList, data.transaction_id]);
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  callApi()
}, [dataList])

const callApi = async () => {
  if (dataList && dataList.length > 0) {
    axios.put("/api/v1/updates", {
      params: {
        "refundIdList": dataList, //dataList should have some value but it contains nothing.
        "refundReason": refundMsg,
        "reasonEtcReason": data.reasonEtcReason,
        "feeUserPay": data.feeUserPay ? 1 : 0,
        "penaltyFeeUserPay": data.penaltyFeePartnerPay ? 1 : 0,
        "penaltyFeeUtPay:": data.penaltyFeeUtPay ? 1 : 0,
        "penaltyFeePartnerPay": data.penaltyFeePartnerPay ? 1 : 0,
      }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("response", res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error : ", err);
    })
  }

}


const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
  let refundMsg = "";
  getSortedId();
}

return (
  <Button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit()} > Save </Button>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the significant example. that was really helpful. it seems like I alway have to use hooks after setState.